# How to submit a form from another component when the modal OK button is clicked (bootstrap vue)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

In my Vue app, I have a component that handles a simple form named `TodoForm`.
Using bootstrap-vue, i would like to submit this form when the OK button of a bootstrap modal is pressed.

The code looks like this:

```html
<b-modal id="todo-form-modal">
    <todo-form />
</b-modal>
```

I don't want to put the modal component inside the `TodoForm` component since the `TodoForm` component only handles the form behavior, not the container where it is displayed.

I could also disable the OK button and put a button inside the form myself, but i'm sure there is a proper, a better way to submit this form (it is more like an exercise than a real project with an actual deadline).

I found the `@ok` event in the doc (triggered when the OK button is pressed), which is nice but i'm struggling to understand how i could use it to call a `onSubmit()` method inside the `TodoForm`.

For instance, it looks like this:

```html
<b-modal id="todo-form-modal" @ok="something">
    <todo-form />
</b-modal>
```

Ideally, the `@ok="something"` should call a method inside the `TodoForm` component.

How can I achieve this **the right way** ?

Comment: Not sure what the down-vote was here, and it's an issue I have, so +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @mapawa's answer:

```html
<template>
  <b-modal ... @ok="handleOk">
    <todo-form ref="todoform" ...></todo-form>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
import TodoForm from 'somewhere/todoform'

export default {
  components: { TodoForm },
  methods: {
    handleOk(bvEvt) {
      // This assumes the root element of the todo form is the <form>
      this.$refs.todoform.$el.submit()
      // Alternatively, if your Todo Form exposes a submit method
      this.$refs.todoform.submit()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to **reference** the parent component in the child component. You can use the `ref` attribute for this. I can't possibly explain this better than the official docs, so take a look at [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements).

Comment: I can only accept one answer but i gave you my up vote too :) Thanks

Comment: @toyi Fair enough. He actually made the effort to develope a solution specifically solving your problem instead of lazily pointing to the docs.